# Can i use nested loops with vectors in cpp?

Tags: c++

i have a cpp problem and i don't know whats wrong.. maybe you can help me :).
I'm trying to implement a data structure for a graph. In this graph i will connect some nodes, which have a small euclidean distance, but at the second iteration, my iterator will point to 0x0. This case appears only, if i give the distance of those two nodes to std::cout. Here is my code:

```
for(vector<Node*>::iterator n1 = g->getNodes().begin(); n1 != g->getNodes().end(); ++n1)
{
    for(vector<Node*>::iterator n2 = g->getNodes().begin(); n2 != g->getNodes().end(); ++n2)
    {
        if(*n2 == 0)
        {
            // This will be entered after the first iteration of n2.
            cout << "n2 null" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        double distance = (*n1)->getDistance(*n2); // just euclidean distance
        if(distance <= minDistance)
        {
            // This works fine:
            cout << "(" << *n1 << "," << *n2 << ") << endl;

            // This brings me a "Segmentation fault"
            cout << "(" << *n1 << " , " << *n2 << ") -> " << distance << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this owed by the nested loops? Can any body tell me my fault? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Here is some more code:
**node.h**

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
private:
    int x, y, z;
public:
    Node(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {
    }

    inline int getX()           { return x; }
    inline int getY()           { return y; }
    inline int getZ()           { return z; }

    inline double getDistance(Node* other)
    {
        return sqrt(pow(x-other->getX(), 2) + pow(y-other->getY(), 2) + pow(z-other->getZ(), 2));
    }
};

#endif
```

**graph.h**

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H_
#define GRAPH_H_

#include <vector>
#include "node.h"
using namespace std;

class Graph
{
private:
    vector<Node*> nodes;
public:
    ~Graph()
    {
        while(!nodes.empty())
        {
            delete nodes.back(), nodes.pop_back();
        }
    }
    inline vector<Node*> getNodes()             { return nodes; }
    inline int getCountNodes()                  { return nodes.size(); }
    bool createNode(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        nodes.push_back(new Node(x, y, z));
        return true;
    };
#endif
```

**main.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include "model/graph.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Graph *g = new Graph();
    int nodeDistance = 100;
    for(int z = 0; z <= 300; z += nodeDistance)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x <= 500; x += nodeDistance)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y <= 300; y += nodeDistance)
            {
                g->createNode(x, y, z);
            }
        }
    }

    for(vector<Node*>::iterator n1 = g->getNodes().begin(); n1 != g->getNodes().end(); ++n1)
    {
        for(vector<Node*>::iterator n2 = g->getNodes().begin(); n2 != g->getNodes().end(); ++n2)
        {
            if(*n2 == 0)
            {
                // This will be entered after the first iteration of n2.
                cout << "n2 null" << endl;
                continue;
            }

            double distance = (*n1)->getDistance(*n2); // just euclidean distance
            if(distance <= nodeDistance)
            {
                // This works fine:
                cout << "(" << *n1 << "," << *n2 << ") << endl;

                // This brings me a "Segmentation fault"
                cout << "(" << *n1 << " , " << *n2 << ") -> " << distance << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    delete g;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When `*n2 == 0`, that means your vector contains a NULL pointer. There's nothing wrong with *this* code, the bug must lie elsewhere in where you create the vector returned by `getNodes()`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with nested iteration. The bug is somewhere else, in the code that you did not include in your question. Please post a complete, minimal, compilable example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: If i don't print the distance, the line `cout << "(" << *n1 << "," << *n2 << ") << endl;` will be executed and tells me, there are no null pointers:

Comment: Again, there is still not enough information for us to determine what might be wrong. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jagemue What does `getNodes()` do?  Does it return a reference, or does it return a copy?  If it's a copy, then that is a problem.

Comment: Aha, you are returning a copy.  Bad, bad.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah, thats it. Thanks =))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One major issue is that your `getNodes` function returns a copy of a vector, not the original vector.  Therefore your iterators you use in the loops are not iterating over the same vector.

Instead, the iterators you're using in the nested loops are iterating over 4 different (but equivalent) vectors instead of the actual vector from the object in question.

There is nothing wrong in returning a copy of a vector in general.  However when you do this, you have to make sure you call such a function if you really want a *copy*, and not the same vector.   Using the `getNodes` function as you used it is not a valid usage in terms of what you are trying to accomplish.

The error is here:

```
inline vector<Node*> getNodes()  { return nodes; }
```

The fix:

```
inline vector<Node*>& getNodes() { return nodes; }
```

The latter ensures that a reference to the actual vector in question is returned, not a copy of the actual vector.  You can add an additional function that returns the vector as a copy if you want to still have the functionality available.

Comment: One follow-up question: Why does returning the copy instead of a reference cause this error? Even though it's a copy, the copies are valid pointers pointing at the correct objects, right? You can still iterate through the copies.

Comment: @mock_blatt: The `.end()` values for different vectors are different, so the iterator loop walks off the end of the vector because the iterator never matches the end value it expects.

Comment: Ohhh it took me a few to understand. At first I thought that still wouldn't be a problem because n1 and n2 were just iterating through their respective vectors, but like Paul said there are FOUR vectors at play, and the begin and end iterators are from different copies. Thanks.