# C++ Custom Stack Printing Issues

Tags: c++

I am creating a custom class Stack to store a couple string variables. When I attempt to print the stack, it says that the stack is always empty, which is not correct. I am using vectors to represent the custom stack, so the way I go about my print method should work, but for some reason it does not. What is my error? Is it in my `isEmpty` method?

```
void stack::printStack() {

    std::vector<std::string> v;

    if(stack::isEmpty()) {

        std::cout << "Stack is empty! " << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i != v.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a copy of the underlying vector with

```
std::vector<std::string> stack::getVector();
```

This results in all calls such as `stack::getVector().push_back(n);` making no modifications to the `stack::v`, but modifying the returned temporary instead.

I don't see, why you shouldn't be using `v` directly in the member functions:

```
v.push_back(n);
```

Or, if you don't want to do that (for some reason), make `getVector` return both reference-to-const and reference-to-non-const:

```
std::vector<std::string> const& stack::getVector() const { return v; };
std::vector<std::string> &stack::getVector()             { return v; };
```

Note, that you're breaking encapsulation with `std::vector<std::string> &` returning overload.

Comment: Okay I see. The reason I can't use v directly is because it is a private variable in my header file. Or are you saying I should declare it in each method like 
        `void stack::push(std::string n){ // Pushes the given string onto the stack
     std::vector<std::string> v;
     v.push_back(n);

        }`

Comment: You can use it! It's a member of the class, it's private only to the "outside world". If `stack` could not use it, what would?

Comment: Note also what @PaulMcKenzie mentioned, don't know why you removed the relevant code I answered though.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a local variable here:

```
void stack::printStack(){

      std::vector<std::string> v;
```

That `v` is not the same as the `v` member variable.  That local `v` is empty, thus your loop never prints.

Also, use descriptive variable names.  Using a single letter variable name such as `v` is not a good idea.

Also, with respect to return a vector by reference or copy, see this question and answer:  [Returning vector copies.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041907/can-i-use-nested-loops-with-vectors-in-cpp)

So do you want to return a copy of the vector, or do you want to return the actual vector?  If it is the latter, return a reference, if it's the former, then return a copy (as your current code is doing).  Note that there are implications in returning a copy as opposed to returning a reference (as the link shows).