# Segmentation fault in iterator dereferencing

Tags: c++, vector, reference, iterator, dereference

The code listed below triggers a segmentation fault in the iterator based loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    A(unsigned id = 0) {id_ = id;}
    unsigned get_id() {return id_;}
private:
    unsigned id_;
};

class B {
public:
    B() {}
    B(std::vector<A*> entries) : entries_(entries) {}
    const std::vector<A*> get_entries() const {
        return entries_;
    }
private:
    std::vector<A*> entries_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A*> entries;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        entries.push_back(new A(i));
    }
    B b(entries);

    // index based access (ok)
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < b.get_entries().size(); i++) {
        std::cout << b.get_entries()[i]->get_id() << std::endl;
    }

    // iterator based access (segmentation fault)
    for (std::vector<A*>::const_iterator i = b.get_entries().begin();
        i != b.get_entries().end();
        ++i) {
        std::cout << (*i)->get_id() << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

On the other hand, the index based loop works ok.

This behaviour is triggered when a copy of the `std::vector` is returned (see: `const std::vector<A*> get_entries() const`) and not a `const` reference to it, as e.g. `const std::vector<A*>& get_entries() const`.
The latter case works fine.

How could this behaviour be explained?

Comment: The object returning from get_entries() creates an iterator and is then destroyed. Afterwards, you try to dereference the iterator on a destroyed container and crash. This happens because objects that return by value and not stored anywhere have very short lives.

Comment: Same issue as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041907/can-i-use-nested-loops-with-vectors-in-cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `get_entries()` returns a vector by value, you're using a different `std::vector<A*>` object every time.  Comparing iterators from different vectors is Undefined Behavior, so even with just `get_entries().begin() != get_entries().end()` you're already in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `get_entries` returns a temporary copy of the vector, not a reference to the original.  So every time you are calling it and grabbing the iterator to a temporary return value, that iterator will be invalid by the time you come to use it.  That leads to undefined behaviour, in which a crash is pretty common.

You have two options here.

**Option 1:** Store the returned vector in a local variable and iterate over that.

**Option 2:** Modify the function to return a reference `const std::vector<A*> & get_entries() const`.