# C++, when should return reference?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

```
class Node{   
private:    
vector<Node*> children;    

public:     
vector< Node* > getChildren ();    
//or    
vector< Node* >& getChildren();
}
```

In the Main function somewhere i have STL sort:

```
**stl::sort((n->getChildren()).begin(),(n->getChildren()).end(),comp);**
```

here comes the problem, if using vector< Node* > getChildren() the code will have bad excess problem, only using vector< Node* >& getChildren() works.
I am confused, why only reference works in this case?

Comment: This question looks very similar to another question I saw today: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34008337/1553090

Comment: Even if this didn't cause a problem, it would still be pointless. Why `sort` a vector and then throw away the sorted vector?

Comment: did you mean `std::sort` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are not returning a reference, `getChildren` will return a new copy of the `vector` each time it is called.

This means that in this line:

```
stl::sort((n->getChildren()).begin(),(n->getChildren()).end(),comp);
```

The first call to `getChildren` returns a different copy than the second call to `getChildren`. This then means that the `begin()` and `end()` are on different vectors, so you will never be able to iterate from one to the other.

When you return a reference, both call return a reference to the same vector, so you can iterate from `begin()` to `end()`

Comment: Make sure you add a `const` version of the function that returns a `const` reference. `vector< Node* > const& getChildren() const;`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @TheDark said (for me it is not stated clearly): 
The reference returns the actual vector that is part of the class. Thus if you make modifications to the vector, the modifications are made on the vector in the class and other functions and the class will see the changes.

If you return a copy, the changes are made to the copy only and the class and other functions will not see the changes.

If you want to sort the vector locally and not sort the vector in the class, you need to do the following (reason provided by @TheDark, for this you can return either a reference or copy):

```
vector< Node* > localVector = n->getChildren();
stl::sort(localVector.begin(), localVector.end(), comp);
```