# Sorting an array with a custom functor in c++ where the mother class is generic

Tags: c++, list, sorting, functor

So I want to  sort an array in the mother class from the child using an object functor. The mother class is generic.

```
template<typename T>
class MotherClass
{
public:
  /* some code */

  std::list<T*> getList();

private:
  std::list<T*> list_;
}
```

The child class uses another class as template

```
class OtherClass
{
public:
  /* some code */

  std::string getName() const;

private:
  std::string name_;
}
```

Here is the functor class

```
class Functor
{
public:
  /* some code */

  bool operator() (OtherClass* a, OtherClass* b) const
  {
    return a->getName() < b->getName();
  }
}
```

Finally, here is the child class

```
class ChildClass : public MotherClass<OtherClass>
{
public:
  /* some code */

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const ChildClass& child);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const ChildClass& child)
{
  Functor functor;
  std::sort(child.getList().begin(), child.getList().end(), functor);

  /* some code */
}
```

When I comment the sorting line in the ChildClass, the solution build without any problem. Though, when it is there, this error happens.

> error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_unchecked_iterator>>'

Anybody can help?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I dont understand your code. e.g.  in the `operator<<` you sort the ´child`s list, but the parameter `child` is `const`

Comment: your `child.getList()` returns a value, thus `child.getList().begin()`  and `child.getList().end()` are iterators from two different containers

Comment: Are you providing the first error message or the last error message?  The first one is more important.

Comment: Your `std::sort` suffers from the same issue as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842901/debug-assertion-error-list-iterators-incompatible/34843702#34843702)

Answer (score 3):

As stated by `std::sort` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) it requires random access iterator, which `std::list` does not provide. That's why `std::list` has it's own method [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) so solution could be:

```
Functor functor;
auto list = child.getList();
list.sort( functor );
```

Note: even if you use container, that supports random access iterator your method would not work, every time you call `child.getList()` you create a new copy, so would you get UB for calling `begin()` and `end()` on 2 different instances. If your idea was to sort data member, you need to return it by reference, which is not a good idea but technically would work:

```
// if getList() returns reference this would work
Functor functor;
child.getList().sort( functor );
```

but better you pass functor to a method of `MotherClass`, which would sort it's 
data.