# Range For Loop over an Element of a Map

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the example below. `config_parser` is an object of a class whose method `variable_map()` returns an object of the type `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>` by value. The first loop gives incorrect or garbage result while the second loop give correct result. What am I missing?

Compilers tested with: GCC 6.3.1, clang 3.9.1, (c++14)

```
 std::vector<std::string> rules = config_parser.variable_map()["CellQRule"];

 for (const auto rule : config_parser.variable_map()["CellQRule"]) {
   std::cout << rule << std::endl;
 }
 for (const auto rule : rules) {
   std::cout << rule << std::endl;
 }
```

The following code also gives correct result for both the loops.

```
 auto map = config_parser.variable_map();
 auto q_rules = map["CellQRule"];

 for (const auto rule : map["CellQRule"]) {
    std::cout << rule << std::endl;
 }
 for (const auto rule : q_rules) {
   std::cout << rule << std::endl;
 }
```

**EDIT** Added that the function returns the variable by value.

Comment: A [mcve] would be a good start.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted.  The error is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not in `variable_map()`? And as a tip try to use `const auto&` instead of `const auto` if you are not modifying the object.

Comment: Does `config_parser.variable_map()` return a copy or a reference? I don't know how the compiler actually builds the iteration from the range based loop, but if it takes your expression twice and appends `.begin()` and `.end()` then `variable_map()` would be called twice. If that returns a copy, the iterators returned by `begin` and `end` don't belong to the same `vector`.

Comment: If your intention is to return the actual member of `config_parser` that represents that string vector, then you should be returning a reference, not a copy.  Without an [mcve], we have no idea if this was your intention or not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I apologize for the lack of minimum working example. I tried to reduce the example, but with reduced examples, it worked! I had not paid attention to the difference between return by reference and return by value problem.

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik ok, now that you're returning by value, is that what you really wanted to do?  Note that returning by value returns a copy, and returning a copy when you really want to return the actual reference to the member can [get you into this trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041907/can-i-use-nested-loops-with-vectors-in-cpp/30042185#30042185)

Comment: Yes, I did not want to return by value. I wanted to return by const reference, but that was a bug in the program I had overlooked. It got triggered only when I tried to do this. Thanks. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `config_parser.variable_map()` returns by value, then for `config_parser.variable_map()["CellQRule"];`, `config_parser.variable_map()` will return a temporary `std::map`, then `config_parser.variable_map()["CellQRule"];` will return a reference to `std::vector` belonging to the temporary `std::map`.

The [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation) is equivalent with

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 

    } 
}
```

Note the temporary will be destroyed after the full expression; so after `auto && __range = range_expression ;`, `__range` will become a dangled reference; then, UB.

On the other hand, when you use named variable instead of temporary, everything works fine.