# c++ map iterator doesn't start from the first item

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I'm trying to iterate over a map for some reason the iterator doesn't start from the first item.

```
const Noeud* origine = &noeuds.at(nomorigine);
map<string, Noeud>::iterator it;
origine->seeRoutes(); //Prints n5: n4 n6
it = origine->getRoutes().begin();
cout<<it->first<<endl; //Prints n4.
for(it = origine->getRoutes().begin(); it != origine->getRoutes().end(); it++){
    cout<<it->first<<endl; //Prints n6.
}

void Noeud::seeRoutes() const{
    cout<<getNom()<<": ";
    for(auto it = routes.begin(); it != routes.end(); it++){
        cout<<it->first<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

I've tried using `auto` but the result is the same. What could be the cause of this problem?

Here is the class for Noeud:

```
class Noeud{
  public:
    string getNom() const;
    void setNom(const string& nom);
    void ajouterRoute(const string& nomRoute, const Noeud noeud);
    map<string, Noeud> getRoutes() const;
    void seeRoutes() const;

  private:
    string nom;
    map<string, Noeud> routes;
};
```

Comment: Why are you not using ++it in the for loop?

Comment: Similar mistake and answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041907/can-i-use-nested-loops-with-vectors-in-cpp).

Comment: @Davar I thought there was no difference between ++it and it++. Is it always better to pre-increment in a for loop?

Comment: @AnthonyGauthier [Use `++i` if you don't have a specific reason to use `i++`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24904/3309790)

Comment: @AnthonyGauthier The `++it` operator takes the `it`, increments `it` and then returns `it`. The `it++` takes the `it`, makes copy of `it`, increments `it` and then returns the copy. In the iterator for loop it doesn't matter, because you are looking at the `it`, not taking into account that it returned some copy, but it has still created a copy (I'm not sure if automatic optimization are able to catch this.). One example you can try:
`int main() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    std::cout << x++ << " " << ++y;
}`
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

Comment: ...and read @songyuanyao link

Comment: Perhaps don't do `map<string, Noeud> getRoutes() const;`, but instead create a `map<string, Noeud>::const_iterator getRoutesBegin() const;` and `map<string, Noeud>::const_iterator getRoutesEnd() const;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getRoutes()` returns by value, that means what `origine->getRoutes()` returns is a [temporary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) which will be destroyed after full-expression. After that `it` becomes dangled, any dereference on it leads to [UB](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

You can use a named variable to avoid this problem. e.g.

```
map<string, Noeud> m = origine->getRoutes();
it = m.begin();
...
```

And note that for the same reason, in the for loop `origine->getRoutes()` is invoked twice and returns two irrelevant objects. The iterators got from them are incompatible, comparing them is ill-formed.

Comment: It works, thank you. So the only way to avoid this problem is storing the map in a named variable before the loop?

Comment: @AnthonyGauthier Depending on the design, changing `getRoutes` to return-by-reference could solve the issue too. Make certain to return a valid reference.