# Accessing a nested element inside a range_expression returns incomplete map (segfaults)

Tags: c++, data-structures, nested, c++17

Accessing a element in a map of maps inside a range-based for loop's range_expression returns an incomplete map.

My minimum working example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Container {
  private:
    std::map<int,std::map<int,int>> contents = {{1, {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}}};
  public:
    auto getContents() {return contents;};
};

int main(){
  auto container = Container();
  for (const auto& [k,v] : container.getContents().at(1)) {
    std::cout << "key: " << k << "    value: " << v << std::endl;
  }
}
```

results in a segfault

```
key: 2    value: 3
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

I tried debugging this in lldb:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set --file test.cpp --line 13
Breakpoint 1: 2 locations.
(lldb) run
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100001515 a.out`main at test.cpp:13:38
   10
   11   int main(){
   12     auto container = Container();
-> 13     for (const auto& [k,v] : container.getContents().at(1)) {
   14       std::cout << "key: " << k << "    value: " << v << std::endl;
   15     }
   16   }
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
(lldb) p container.getContents()
(std::__1::map<int, std::__1::map<int, int, std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, int> > >, std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, std::__1::map<int, int, std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, int> > > > > >) $0 = size=1 {
  [0] = {
    first = 1
    second = size=2 {
      [0] = (first = 2, second = 3)
      [1] = (first = 4, second = 5)
    }
  }
}
(lldb) p container.getContents().at(1)
(std::__1::map<int, std::__1::map<int, int, std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, int> > >, std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, std::__1::map<int, int, std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, int> > > > > >::mapped_type) $1 = size=2 {
  [0] = (first = 2, second = 3)
}
```

The last line says that the sub-map I want to iterate over has two elements (size=2) but only the first entry ({2,3}) is present.

Making a slight change to my code

```cpp
int main(){
  auto container = Container();
  auto contents = container.getContents();
  for (const auto& [k,v] : contents.at(1)) {
    std::cout << "key: " << k << "    value: " << v << std::endl;
  }
}
```

gives me the output I want:

```
key: 2    value: 3
key: 4    value: 5
```

but I am still curious as to why the first approach is not working.

Comment: Returning a copy of the container instead of a reference to the actual container is a common mistake made.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041907/can-i-use-nested-loops-with-vectors-in-cpp/30042185#30042185) for a similar error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto getContents() {return contents;}
```

This effectively makes a copy of `contents` and returns a new object, and not a reference to the `contents` member of `this` class instance. This means that the caller has two options for dealing with it: store it somewhere, as a named object in the caller's context, or use it as a temporary object and immediately destroy it after it is no longer needed.

```
for (const auto& [k,v] : container.getContents().at(1)) {
```

This uses the result of `getContents()`, invoking its `at()` method. If you look at the description of `std::map::at`, you find that it returns a reference to the map's contents.

That's great, but the results of `getContents()` are not stored anywhere, and after `at()` is called this temporary object gets destroyed, and the returned reference is now a dangling reference. The immediate attempt to use it, for range iteration, becomes undefined behavior.

In the 2nd example, `at()` comes from a named object, not a temporary object, that remains in scope and continues to exist for the duration of range iteration, and that's why it works.

Note that returning a new object from `getContents()` is wasteful. It makes an extra copy of the entire map. If you return a reference instead, the first version of the range iteration will also work, as long as the object whose `getContents()` method was invoked remains in scope and does not get destroyed.